# Math Function to convert Digits in Android - Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, math, floor, ceil

I am hoping for below outcomes :

If Input => 25.69 - OutCome should be 25.6

If Input => -0.40 - OutCome should be -0.4

If Input => -0.004 - OutCome should be 0 or 0.0

To achive this I have tries as below :

```
current=25.69
Log.e(">>> ceil ",">>> "+Math.ceil(current))
Log.e(">>> round ",">>> "+Math.round(current))
Log.e(">>> floor ",">>> "+Math.floor(current))
```

But getting out come as :

ceil: >>> 26.0
round: >>> 26
floor: >>> 25.0

**How can I get 25.6 ?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend using `BigDecimal` for complex rounding behaviors:

```java
double current = 25.69;
double truncatedDouble = BigDecimal.valueOf(current).setScale(1, RoundingMode.DOWN).doubleValue();
System.out.println(truncatedDouble);
```

prints

```
25.6
```